# Can we delete this folder?

Tags: windows-10, storage

after runned WinDir I figured out that I had this folder who is 3GB:

```
C:\Users\Jerome\AppData\Local\Packages\microsoft.windowscommunicationsapps_8wekyb3d8bbwe
```

And after some googling I founded that this folder is linked with **Microsoft Live**  so can I delete it without having any errors or problems after ?

Comment: Those 8wekyb3d8bbwe files are included by Windows Store, for "built-in" apps.  I discovered while troubleshooting Edge once that Windows will restore them without prompting after some time.

Comment: this is the mail app. in the settings change option to only download mails for last week and not all mails

Comment: It is not recommended to delete it if you are not sure of the consequences

Comment: The folder is required if you want specific UWP applications to function.

Comment: @magicandre1981 so I'll check my mails settings

Comment: yes, do this and only download mail from 1 week to have smaller cache on disk to reduce the size

Answer (score 1):

It can be deleted, although if you use Windows Outlook frequently, you will not have the attachments downloaded.